# what are the properties of anti-magic?

Tags: magic, artificial-intelligence, robots, balancing-magic-systems

In my fantasy world, magic has four specific properties:

1. Magic is a product of living things. Wherever there is life, there is magic. The greater the concentration of living things, the more magic there is.
2. Magic is neither a particle, nor a wave. It's some sort of strange, wibbly-wobbly thing, just kind of...there. It doesn't take up space, it doesn't have mass, it doesn't produce radiation, and we can't see it, but we know it's there.
3. It's incredibly malleable, and incredibly unstable. Literally anything can cause it to change state, and it can change into anything; energy, waves, particles, and anything inbetween.
4. Because magic is so unstable, it can effect the properties and composition of non-magic things.

Now, because magic comes from life, it's specially tuned to the will of lifeforms. Living organisms have a special proficiency for manipulating magic as they see fit.

So, naturally, it would stand to reason that artificial life (robots, artificial intelligence, etc.) produces anti-magic, and can manipulate it as it sees fit.

The obvious property of anti-magic is that it eliminates regular magic, but what would its other properties be? Would it be just like regular magic, except negatively charged? Would it have the opposite properties? If a robot used it to create particles, would it make antiparticles instead? What would make the most sense?

Comment: This is a perfect example of an open-ended opinion-based question. It would be mildly interesting to understand how you decided that it is possible, even in principle, to form a consensus about what answers are better than others. (And the sentence *"naturally, it would stand to reason that artificial life (robots, artificial intelligence, etc.) produces anti-magic, and can manipulate it as it sees fit"* is *both* a non-sequitur (no, it does not stand to reason) *and in addition* equates machinery with life.)

Comment: Who decided artificial intelligence isn't alive?  And are you suggesting everything with a microchip produces anti magic?  Sorry this question is too broad and opinion based.

Comment: Seconded Trevor's point. I'm not sure that it 'stands to reason' that 'artificial life' produces anti-magic.

Comment: If robots (and not zombies) are anti-magic, then perhaps grey goo

Answer (score 1):

I would say, based on how you've set up magic to be, that anti-magic would simply be a negating, or regulating / balancing factor.

Your four properties of magic take away any potential for it to be scientifically explained, much like the Force from Star Wars where it's always just a field that exists around and within us, but isn't something as defined as a particle field. Since it's that unstable and unclassified in this case, I think an anti-solution to magic would be something that removes the 'field' all together, having anti-magic be more like a force that regulates the change magic can bring and effectively brings everything back down to reality.

The concept of artificial life producing anti-magic seems to be more of a narrative / symbolic choice than one that would fit well with countering magic properties as you've established, as we've seen the history of AI grow from bare-bones to modern machine learning and understand a lot about what goes on underneath the hood. Robots are programmed responses, and with the same logic I'd say a rock could produce anti-magic. You *could* also argue that inorganic materials do naturally produce an anti-magic aura or the like, and that the artificial will of the robot is what allows them to produce it, but that's another discussion post.

**TL;DR** Magic is the wild card in the situation, and therefore anti-magic wouldn't be 'negative particles' so much as regular particles that have the ability to negate the weird magic.